# Typing "hack" in terminal

Tags: command-line

While I was experimenting and trying out new things on Ubuntu, I typed "hack", opening the terminal. It shows "Hello , welcome to hack".
What does that command do exactly? I want to know more about it. Please help me out.

Answer (score 4):

"hack" is a game from "bsdgames" package.

> Hack is a 1982 roguelike video game that introduced shops as gameplay elements and expanded available monsters, items, and spells. It later became the basis for NetHack.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hack_(Unix_video_game)